# Cannot cast type pine-script error? Looking for a workaround

Tags: pine-script

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error in pinescript when I try to plot the exit signal?

**Error: Cannot cast type error 'series[bool]' to expected type 'series[float]' in 'plot_2'?**

It doesn't appear for anything else. As soon as I turn plot on it appears.

I'm not familiar with this error in pinescript and don't recall seeing anything like this in the past. If someone can educate me what I'm doing wrong that'll be great

Here is the code:

```
fish = 0.0
fish := (2.5)*(0.5 * log((1 + v1) / (1 - v1))) + (0.5 * nz(fish[1]))
fishColor = sig > 0 ? color.green : sig < 0 ? color.red : color.black

plot(fish, title="FisherTransform", color=fishColor, linewidth=2)




highpassLength = 48
ssfLength = 10
numberOfPoles = input(title="Number of Poles", type=input.integer, defval=2, options=[2, 3])
src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)

PI = 2 * asin(1)

twoPoleSuperSmootherFilter(src, length) =>
    arg = sqrt(2) * PI / length
    a1 = exp(-arg)
    b1 = 2 * a1 * cos(arg)
    c2 = b1
    c3 = -pow(a1, 2)
    c1 = 1 - c2 - c3

    ssf = 0.0
    ssf := c1 * src + c2 * nz(ssf[1]) + c3 * nz(ssf[2])

threePoleSuperSmootherFilter(src, length) =>
    arg = PI / length
    a1 = exp(-arg)
    b1 = 2 * a1 * cos(1.738 * arg)
    c1 = pow(a1, 2)

    coef2 = b1 + c1
    coef3 = -(c1 + b1 * c1)
    coef4 = pow(c1, 2)
    coef1 = 1 - coef2 - coef3 - coef4

ssf = 0.0
ssf := coef1 * src + coef2 * nz(ssf[1]) + coef3 * nz(ssf[2]) + coef4 * nz(ssf[3])

roofingFilter(src, highpassLength, ssfLength, numberOfPoles) =>
    alphaArg = 2 * PI / (highpassLength * sqrt(2))

    alpha = 0.0
    alpha := cos(alphaArg) != 0
         ? (cos(alphaArg) + sin(alphaArg) - 1) / cos(alphaArg)
         : nz(alpha[1])

    highpass = 0.0
    highpass := pow(1 - (alpha / 2), 2) * (src - 2 * nz(src[1]) + nz(src[2])) + 2 * (1 - alpha) * nz(highpass[1]) - pow(1 - alpha, 2) * nz(highpass[2])

    numberOfPoles == 2
     ? twoPoleSuperSmootherFilter((highpass + nz(highpass[1])) / 2, ssfLength)
     : threePoleSuperSmootherFilter((highpass + nz(highpass[1])) / 2, ssfLength)

erf = roofingFilter(src, highpassLength, ssfLength, numberOfPoles)

erfColor = erf >= 0.0 ? #0ebb23 : #ff0000

plot(erf, title="ERF", linewidth=2, color=erfColor, transp=0)

//Center Line
hline(0, title="Zero line", color=color.black)

//exitlong  = (fish < 0.000)

exitlong = (fish <0) and (erf <0)

plot(exitlong, title="Exit", color=fishColor, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `exitlong` variable is `bool` type. `series` argument of `plot()` function expects *integer* or *float* types.

If you really want to plot the value of a *boolean* variable, you can do the following:

```
exitlong = (fish <0) and (erf <0)

plot(exitlong ? 1 : 0, title="Exit", color=fishColor, linewidth=2)
```

With `exitlong ? 1 : 0`, you basically convert *bool* to *int*.